# How can I use values from one database to insert them into a table in another database?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert multiple values from one database into another.

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO organization (`id`, `company_id`, `code`, `name`, `path`) 
(SELECT 100 + id_status FROM database2.employeestatus), '1',
(SELECT 100 + id_status FROM database2.employeestatus),
(SELECT tagline FROM database2.employeestatus),
(SELECT 100 + id_status FROM database2.employeestatus);
```

The issue is that when I try to run it this way, it breaks, ofc. But when I execute it one by one, for example:

```
SELECT 100 + id_status FROM database2.employeestatus
```

Then it returns all rows I need. There are about 40 rows, and I don't want to enter them manually.

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: `insert into organization  (col...) select  100 + id_status, 1, etc from database2.employeestatus ...`

Answer (score 2):

Try using an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT`:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO organization (id, company_id, code, name, path)
SELECT 100 + id_status, '1', 100 + id_status, tagline,
       100 + id_status
FROM database2.employeestatus;
```

The problem with your current approach is that each of the subqueries you have in the select clause themselves return more than one record/value.  This doesn't make sense as a select list can only contain single scalar values.

Comment: Thank you so much, it makes sense and you helped me a lot!

I just have a follow up question:

delete FROM organization o
WHERE o.id IN (select 100 + s.id_status FROM database2.status s) 

For this one, how can I delete those fields from that select from 2nd database? It's most likely an oversight on my end but I can't pinpoint the exact problem since it works when I replace delete from with select * from...

Comment: That sounds like a great follow-up question, but it doesn't belong here, it belongs in a new question.

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion, I created it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64046225/deleting-data-with-select-from-another-database