# Deleting data with select from another database

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete data from one database with select from another one.

```
delete FROM organization o 
WHERE o.id IN 
(select 100 + s.id_status FROM database2.status s)
```

For this one, how can I delete those fields from that select from 2nd database? It's most likely an oversight on my end but I can't pinpoint the exact problem since it works when I replace delete from with select * from...

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what you want to do.  Your intention is not clear.

Comment: Not sure this is a good idea. Databases are supposed to be isolated. Maybe you should retrieve all the IDs you want to delete, then use another query for the deletion.

Comment: I have a few rows of data in database 1 - table organization. Column id in organization table has the same value as id_status column from another database in a table named status.

Comment: If `o.id` has the same value as `s.id_status` then why would you add `100` to the `s.id_status` column?

Comment: @GuillaumeF. no, this is not true at all. There are lots of reasons why you have data in different databases, yet required to interact with each other! Typical use case is having a staging database for ETL to import data into mysql and then merge that data with your production tables in a separate database!

Comment: @SS_DBA Sorry, o.status has 100 + s.id_status. It's always 100 + s.id_status, even during import from that table.

Comment: @Shadow : What you describe should be handled in a schema, not a database.

Comment: @GuillaumeF. In mysql these two concepts are actually the same...

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to delete from both tables? If so use JOIN form and multiple-table delete

```
DELETE t1.*, t2.*
FROM organization t1
JOIN database2.status t2 ON t1.id = t2.id_status  + 100
```

or

```
DELETE t1.*, t2.*
FROM organization t1
JOIN database2.status t2 ON t1.id - 100 = t2.id_status
```

If `organization` table is small then 2nd variant is preferred. Of course the index by `database2.status (id_status)` must exist for improvement.

---

> No, I just want to delete data from organization since status has to remain intact because it is used for importing data into other tables

If so simply use `DELETE t1.*` instead of `DELETE t1.*, t2.*`.

Comment: No, I just want to delete data from organization since status has to remain intact because it is used for importing data into other tables. :)